# How to passing Value from a function to another class with python

Tags: python

Here I have 2 different classes called `c_elementOptFrame` (lets call it class `a`) and `c_elementFigFrame` (and this is class `b`). In class `a`, I have radio button object, these button will change an image in which I construct with label in class `b`, in other words, I wanted to change this image when I click those radio button. The radio button has been set up with method called `react` , in this method I wanted to pass a value (string) to class `b`, so that class `b` will use this value to change the image. But it doesn't work as I expected. The value has been passed to class `b` (I printed the value) but the image doesn't come up, I tried several ways but I still couldn't do it yet. so this is my code, please let me know if you have couple of suggestions or an alternative to do it. Thank you

code:

```
class c_elementOptFrame(QFrame):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(c_elementOptFrame,self).__init__()

    self.setVisible(True)
    self.setMaximumWidth(150)
    self.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Plain)
    self.setFrameShape(QFrame.Box)
    self.setLineWidth(1)
    self.setFrameStyle(QFrame.StyledPanel)

    #layoutmanager
    layout = QVBoxLayout()

    #all objects inside this frame
    strel_lab = QLabel("Element Types")
    strel_lab.setContentsMargins(0,0,10,10)

    group_box = QGroupBox('Structural Element') 
    opts_group = QButtonGroup()
    opts_group.setExclusive(True)

    beam_but = QRadioButton("Beams")
    slab_but = QRadioButton("Slabs")
    beam_but.toggled.connect(self.react_1)
    slab_but.toggled.connect(self.react_2)

    opts_group.addButton(beam_but)
    opts_group.addButton(slab_but)

    group_box.setLayout(layout)

    concls_lab = QLabel("Concrete Class")
    concls_lab.setContentsMargins(0,15,10,10)

    concls_opt = QComboBox()
    concls_opt.addItem("C30")
    concls_opt.addItem("C40")
    concls_opt.addItem("C50")

    mod_but = QPushButton("Modify Parameter", self)
    mod_but.clicked.connect(self.modifyParam)

    create_but = QPushButton("Create Model", self)
    create_but.setDisabled(False)
    create_but.clicked.connect(self.nextFrame)

    #add objects to layout
    layout.addWidget(strel_lab)
    layout.addWidget(beam_but)
    layout.addWidget(slab_but)
    layout.addWidget(concls_lab)
    layout.addWidget(concls_opt)
    layout.addWidget(mod_but)
    layout.addStretch()
    layout.addWidget(create_but)

    self.setLayout(layout)


  def react_1(self, enabled):
    if enabled:
        pict_path = 1
        c_elementFigFrame(pict_path)

class c_elementFigFrame(QFrame):
  def __init__(self, pict_path):
    super(c_elementFigFrame,self).__init__()

    self.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Plain)
    self.setFrameShape(QFrame.Box)
    self.setLineWidth(1)
    self.setFrameStyle(QFrame.StyledPanel)

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    pict = QLabel('Test')
    pict.sizeHint()

    pixmap = QPixmap()

    if pict_path == 1:
        print(True)
        pixmap.load('beam.png')
        pict.setPixmap(pixmap)
    #else:    
        #pixmap = QPixmap(pict_path)
        #pict.setPixmap(pixmap)


    layout.addWidget(pict)

    self.setLayout(layout)
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly. It's critical for understanding Python programs.

Comment: thank you for your information, I just copy the code from my eclipse to the post editor, and it such a mess since I am new here. :D

Comment: WHen you copy your code into SO, use the `{}` tool to mark it as code, and all the original formatting should be maintained.

Comment: The question says that you want clicking the button to *change* an image object of class `c_elementFigFrame`. But there doesn't seem to be any object of that class -- until one is *created* in `react_1`, which doesn't sound like what you wanted to do.

Comment: I was thinking like, the method `react_1` will give a signal to one of the object inside class `c_elementFigFrame` which is `pixmap`, so if the value pass by `react_1` equals to 1, then if condition inside class b will be triggered. the print method inside if condition is work but the pixmap doesn't work.